# Counting the Number of times a text appears in column based on condition of two or more columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, countif

I have 2 columns in my worksheet. Containing the Month and status.

[image: Figure1]

I want to count the number of times Each status appears for particular month and it should provide the result dynamically whenever i insert a new row in the figure 1.  Figure 2 below displays the required result.

[image: Figure2]

I can do the same with the pivot table but the previous charts were based on tables calculations to make the charts or dashboard more dynamic.

Comment: What have you attempted to make this work? This is not a formula/script writing service, so we want to see what you have tried so far. You tagged [countif], so what have you tried? Are these tables on the same sheet? Different workbooks? Post what formula(s) you are working with. We will help you from there, but we are not here to do it for you.

Comment: @CharlieRB The formula i am using is for say counting the month of july with live status is =COUNTIFS(AK:AK,"July",AA:AA,"Live"). The chart would be on different sheet (main dashboard) and the data in the other. The grand total for live is calculated with the formula =COUNTIF(AA:AA,"Live")

Comment: What is the problem? Is it giving you an error? Not the results you expect? I can see from your example tables that some status cells are blank, which `COUNTIFS` will not assume to be "same as above". Also, "Being Updated" and "Being Update" are not the same, so one will not be counted.

Comment: The calculations gets removed from the sheet  once i apply the filer on the table containing the data. Both are on the same sheet @CharlieRB. Apologies i am new to excel

Comment: Blank is another category wont the countifs work if use the formula  as  COUNTIFS(AK:AK,"July",AA:AA," ") .Moreover "Being update"  was just a spelling mistake which would be same as "Being updated" .@CharlieRB

Comment: Excel deletes the formula when the filter is applied (formula is gone when you remove the filter)? Or does it just stop working as you expect?

Comment: Yes, you can could blanks. I didn't realize that was on purpose.

Comment: the Figure 2 where i am writing all the calculations and formula dissapears (some part of it).@CharlieRB

Comment: So, your real question is not how to use the formula, rather how to avoid losing your formulas when filtering?

Comment: @CharlieRB both is there a better way to implement the formula using OFFSET OR INDEX or any other formula so that the data updation in future doesnt effect my formulas

Comment: Since you mentioned you are new to excel I'm not sure if you are having problems with understanding or using the formula. For understanding, I've used countifs (and/or sumifs) as substitutions for pivot tables. Another pro of using countifs instead of pivot tables is you can display rows that may not be in your table, for instance if you didn't have a project in December a pivot would not display December, but the formula would show -0-. For issues with using the formula you'll have to provide more explanation, as the formula looks correct with a possible exception of column references.